# Handling translation strings to languages with inflections on Android

Tags: android, translation

I'm not sure this is the right forum to post this but I'm unsure how to organize my strings in certain scenarios where nouns in certain languages are inflected. It's easier to explain the problem with an example. Consider the following string:

```
<string name="my_string">Show you more information in context with each 
    <xliff:g id="item_name">%s</xliff:g></string>
```

The element `<xliff:g id="item_name">%s</xliff:g>` in this case can be replaced by, for example, "alarm" or "alert" depending on the context in my app. However, this doesn't work with languages that inflect the noun, such as Finnish.

In Finnish, `%s` is substituted with the word "hälytys" (=alarm) in the app though grammatically correct form in this case would be "hälytyksen" (an inflected form of singular alarm in Finnish, caused by a postposition and unfortunately no nice way to circumvent the inflection).

So it seems I can't have this sort of generic string element with replaceable nouns. Do you have any suggestions other than hard-coding the string elements for each possible value of `%s`?

Comment: The only solution I see is two differenciate sentences where the %s noun can be inflected, and sentences wshere it is not the case

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to this problem? I am really interested in this... Our company is using Gettext for Python and I thought that there is maybe some similar way/library to deal with this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no easy solution for this. The only way to get it right is to have full sentences, one for each placeholder word you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put your string this way in string.xml

```
<string name="my_string">Show you more information in context with each &lt;xliff:g id=\"item_name\"&gt; %s &lt;\/xliff:g&gt;</string>
```

From Java

```
String s = String.format(getString(R.string.my_string,"alarm")); //put your dynamic value for alarm
```

Output would be :

```
Show you more information in context with each <xliff:g id="item_name"> alarm </xliff:g>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's what I'm already doing. The problem with this is that the word "alarm" gets an inflection in some languages such as Finnish. So I can't have another string reference with the word "alarm" translated because it can get different forms in different languages. Any ideas?